# JavaFX show photos in ImageView not working

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, scenebuilder

I'm trying to display a photo depending on the BMI of the user.. So for example if your BMI is under 18.5 it will show a thumbs down.

All the images are located in my resource folder. But the image doesn't show up in the program as it should.. I've tried serveral images to see if it had something to do with the resolution. This is my code:

```
 @FXML
private void tellUserStatus(){
    date = new Date();

    if (bmi<18.5){

        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)+"User is underweight - BMI is under 18.5");
        BmiStatusMessage.setVisible(true);
        BmiStatusMessage.setText("You are underweight");

        File underweight= new File("underweight-thumbsdown.png");
        Image image = new Image(underweight.toURI().toString());
        BmiConclusion.setVisible(true);
        BmiConclusion.setImage(image); 
    }
}
```

BmiStatusMessage is a Label, and BmiConclusion is an ImageView. They are both linked with the fxml file.

Comment: Is the file in the root folder of your project?

Comment: Just curious, the `Image` constructor takes a `String`, so why are you creating a file just to convert it to a `String` again?

Comment: Does the file exist? have you tried `underweight.exists()`?

Comment: You say your files are in a resource folder, but your file path does not show this.

Comment: Where does `bmi`'s value come from? Usually I'd expect a `EventHandler` to access some kind of `Control` to retrieve a value...

Comment: @Sedrick I’ve selected the folder as resource root folder. I’ve always done it that way and never had any issues. I’m using IntelliJ and to get the path I just right click and select “Get relative path” and it just gives me the file name, since it’s already in the root folder.

Comment: @fabian It’s defined another place, I just didn’t want to show all of the code :)

Comment: Does `System.out.println` get executed? As mentioned this way of retrieving a value seems unusual to me, so please make sure this is not the source of your issue.

Comment: @fabian yes the System.out.println does get executed

Comment: @Zephyr I tried that, and it returned false. It turned out to be the path, as you guys said. I had to paste the complete path before it worked. Thanks so much for your help